# Deprecation/UnhandledPromiseRejection warning when trying to run bot

Tags: node.js, discord.js

So I’m making a discord bot, and I had a problem with sharding what I fixed. But now I have a different problem that is making my bot unable to run. When I try to run it I get this error.

```
[WS => Manager] Manager was destroyed. Called by:
Error: MANAGER_DESTROYED
    at WebSocketManager.destroy (/root/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:333:54)
    at Client.destroy (/root/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/Client.js:237:13)
    at Client.login (/root/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/Client.js:226:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:94:5)
(node:13) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: FetchError: request to https://discord.com/api/v7/gateway/bot failed, reason: unable to get local issuer certificate
    at RequestHandler.execute (/root/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:93:15)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:94:5)
(node:13) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 3)
(node:13) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I’ve checked my code a lot of times I’ve even rewrote it multiple times. And looked for other things about this on stackoverflow and on other website  but nothing helped.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like an error related to the client login. Try refreshing the bot token. Another solution is to try and update discord package: *npm update discord.js*